# Accumulation point implies strict limit point?

Tags: general-topology

Given a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$, and a subset $A$ of $X$, define $p$ to be a *strict limit point* of $A$ if there exists a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $A \setminus \{p\}$ such that $x_n \rightarrow p$. (Arbogast, *Methods of Applied Mathematics* page 9 - [book here](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/arbogast/appMath08c.pdf))

Is easy to show that if $p$ is a strict limit point of $A$ then $p$ is an accumulation point of $A$.

The converse is also true if the space is first-countable (every point has a countable base of neighbourhoods).

Is the converse also true when the space is not first-countable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relatively simple counterexample: let $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the topology $\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset\} \cup \{X \setminus A: A \text { at most countable }\}$, the so-called [co-countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology) topology. Check that this is indeed a topology. It's indeed not first countable.

Then set $A = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ and $0$ is an accumulation point of $A$. But if $x_n$ is any sequence of points from $A$, then $X \setminus \{x_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is open, contains $0$ and no point of the sequence, $0$ is not a strict limit point of $A$.

If you know ordinals, $\omega_1 + 1$ is also an example with $A = \omega_1$, and this has nicer separation axioms (and is also sequentially compact). This is Giulio's example, essentially.

The class can be broadened to so called [sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space), instead of the more strict first countable. But some condition is needed.

Comment: thanks! I was trying with co-finite topology and don't succeed

Answer (score 0):

No, but the only counterexample occurring to my mind is easy if and only if you know the basics of the theory of ordinals. Well, since there exists a proof in the first-countable case, counterexamples *need* some sort of uncountable construction, and hence you'll *need* something like the theory of ordinals.

Take a well ordered set $\alpha$ whose cofinality is strictly greater than $\aleph_0$. This means that every function $f:\aleph_0\to\alpha$ respecting the order is limited, i.e. there exists $y\in\alpha$ such that, for every $x\in\aleph_0$, $y>f(x)$. Now take $\beta=\alpha\cup\{*\}$, where $*$ is an element greater than any element of $\alpha$. Put on $\beta$ the following topology: a subset $U\subseteq \beta$ is open if $x<y$ and $x\in U$ imply $y\in U$. Except one case: we impose the subset $\{*\}\subseteq\beta$ to be **not** open. It is easy to check that this defines a topology, and that $\{*\}$ is an accumulation point. Still, since the cofinality of $\alpha$ is strictly greater than $\aleph_0$, there cannot be any sequence in $\alpha$ converging to $*$, hence $*$ is not a limit point of $\beta$.